# How to include zero results when querying one single table?

Tags: sql

I have a table called Apartments that has three columns: apartment_type, person, date. It includes the apartment type selected by a certain person and date. I need to count how many people picked each of the apartment types. Some apartment type have 0 population.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT apartment_type, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM  Apartments
GROUP BY apartment_type
```

It works great, but it doesn't include apartment types with a value of 0. Please, help me to correct this query.

Comment: Do you have a table with a list of all the possible apartment types?

Comment: It appears this table would be using apartment_type as a foreign key which references another table, e.g. APARTMENT_TYPE. The way you have explained this issue thus far, you wouldn't be able to get the results you're expecting.

Comment: btw, it would be good if you specified which database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In case some appartment_type have 0 population - your table will not contain any record with that type - so you must add some join from another table, where all apartment types exists. Or use union to create all 0 populated entries.

Something like:

```
SELECT apartment_type, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM  (SELECT * FROM Apartments UNION ALL SELECT apartment_type, 0 as person, 0 as date from SomeTableWithFullListOfTypes group by apartment_type) as tmp
GROUP BY apartment_type
```

Comment: OK, let's say I have a second table called Apartment_type that lists all possible apartment types, and Apartment table that lists all persons and the apartment type they selected. The foreign key is "apartment_type". I need to list all apartment-types and their populations, even if it is 0. How should I join these tables to make it work?

Comment: The text part of your answer is good, but the query you posted doesn't look right.  If anything, by doing that `union all`, it would mess up the `count(*)` in the outer query.  What you want is a simple `left join`.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the query - added group by for second select in union

Comment: You don't need a union here, you need a join like @sstan said.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with Nosyara's answer, but I don't agree with his sample query with the `union all`.  I'm not sure it works, and it's certainly too complicated.

As stated already, if you don't have a table with all the possible apartment types, create one.  Then you can write your query using a simple `left join`:

```
select t.apartment_type, count(a.apartment_type) as total
  from apartment_types t
  left join apartments a
    on a.apartment_type = t.apartment_type
 group by t.apartment_type
```

Note how `count(*)` was replaced by `count(a.apartment_type)`. That change is necessary to have an accurate count in the case where you don't have apartments for a certain apartment type.

Comment: Thank you! What t and a stand for?

Comment: They are aliases.  In this case, `t` is an alias for `apartment_types` and `a` is an alias for `apartments`.  When writing a join, you often need to specify that a column comes from a specific table by prefixing it with the table name. By defining an alias, you can type the shorter alias instead of the full table name when qualifying column names.

Comment: so t.apartment_type is an apartment_type column from apartment_types table, and a.apartment_type is an apartment_type column from apartments table. Is it right?

Comment: What is the difference between your query and the query below posted by Andrew?

Comment: Can I say: 
 `SELECT apartment_type, COUNT(Apartments.apartment_type) AS TOTAL
FROM  Apartment_types 
LEFT JOIN Apartments
ON  Apartments.apartment_type = Apartment_types.apartment_type
GROUP BY apartment_type`

Comment: Answers to your last 3 comments: 1) yes, 2) Basically the same 3) Yes, except you'll probably need to "qualify" the `apartment_type` column in the `group by` clause, otherwise, you'll probably get an error because the column reference is ambiguous.

Comment: Will `GROUP BY Apartment_types.apartment_type' fix the issue?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. and you'll have to do the same for the `select apartment_type`, I just noticed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT apartment_type, COUNT(apartment.*) AS TOTAL
FROM  apartment_type 
left join apartment
on  apartment_type.aparentment_type = apartements.apartment_type
GROUP BY apartment_type
```

Using a left join will give you everything from the left side of the join (so all your types) and anything from the right that matches.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, clarify whether it should be COUNT(apartment.apartment_type) instead of COUNT(apartment.*). I think it should be: `SELECT apartment_type, COUNT(Apartments.apartment_type) AS TOTAL
FROM  Apartment_types 
LEFT JOIN Apartments
ON  Apartments.apartment_type = Apartment_types.apartment_type
GROUP BY apartment_type` Please, check

Comment: `count(apartment.apartment_type)` will return the same as `count(apartment.*)`.  It's just counting every row.